# Self-adjoint extensions and delta potentials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics

Is there a self-adjoint extension of an operator that corresponds to a particle in a box $[a,b] \times [c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with a delta potential, i.e., $-\Delta + \lambda \delta_y $ on $L^2([a,b] \times [c,d])$ ?

All the references I've been able to find mention a particle on the line or  on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You'd need to specify boundary conditions on a box, to begin...

Comment: There is a very (too?) large body of literature on this; you could try Albeverio et al., Solvable models in QM as an entry point.

Comment: I've looked in Solvable Models; unfortunately, they don't have anything on a particle in a box.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Unless I have missed something, I don't think that your form is closable.  (Actually on $H^1_0((a,b) \times (c,d))$ it's not even well defined.)  Intuitively, this shouldn't work: viewed probabilistically you are trying to take a 2D Brownian motion and impose killing at rate $\lambda$ at the point $y$; but almost surely the Brownian motion doesn't hit $y$, so the killing never happens.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I incorrectly assumed that $H^1(\mathbb R^2)$ functions would be continuous.

Comment: So it appears the QF approach only works in 1D, when there are many direct methods available, too.

Comment: I took a look at some papers and apparently what one does is (adapted to the rectangle, as in the OP) consider $-\Delta$ on $C_0^{\infty}(R\setminus\{y\})$ (this of course again will give Dirichlet bc's on $\partial R$). The closure of this operator seems to be symmetric with deficiency $(1,1)$, so the self-adjoint realizations are easily described and one picks one that feels right.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Does the Dirichlet b.c. mean vanishing on the boundary? Also, what are the eigenfunctions with eigenvalue i,-i? Could you point me towards these papers?

Comment: You could try (especially appendix A of) Tudorovskiy et al, "On the theory of cavities with point-like perturbations: part I. General theory"

Comment: @daunpunk: Yes, "Dirichlet" means $u=0$ on $\partial R$. The method I mentioned is discussed in the Albeverio et al. book; if you have MathSciNet access, there are 250 or so papers that quote Albeverio et al., and many of these are on these topics.

Comment: Some more random musings: Let's denote the closure of $-\Delta$ on $C_0^{\infty}(R\setminus \{ y\})$ by $T$. Then it shouldn't be too hard to show that $D(T)=\{u\in H^2(R): u=0 \textrm{ on }\partial R, u(y)=0 \}$. This is a one-dimensional restriction (by the condition $u(y)=0$) of the self-adjoint Dirichlet Laplacian. This gives the claim on the deficiency indices.

Comment: I think there's something simple I'm misunderstanding. I didn't think there were any i,-i eigenfunctions of the Laplacian that could satisfy the Dirichlet boundary condition (i.e., vanish along a rectangle).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following references will be helpful:

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103153 (Self-adjoint extensions of operators and the teaching of quantum mechanics, by G. Bonneau, J. Faraut and G. Valent).

https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/10264/original/gopalakrishnan06.pdf (Self-Adjointness and the Renormalization of Singular Potentials, Bachelor
thesis by S. Gopalakrishnan).

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately, I'd come across both of these, and neither mention the particle in a box with a delta potential.

Answer (score 1):

The paper Ph. Blanchard, R. Figari, A. Mantile "Point Interaction Hamiltonians in Bounded Domains" http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3249 may contain some answers. In any case, if you have an operator $H$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and want to study its perturbations by zero-range potentials, you need to know the integral kernel of the resolvent $R(z)=(H-z)^{-1}$, see the discussion in Section 1.4.3 of J. Brüning, V. Geyler, K. Pankrashkin: Spectra of self-adjoint extensions and applications to solvable Schrödinger operators http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0611088 or the older paper V.A. Geyler, V. A. Margulis, I. I. Chuchaev: Potentials of zero radius and Carleman operators, Siberian Math. J. 36 (1995) 714–726.